# Detect if 2sxc Module is the Original or from IRenderService

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

As the title says, I need a way in a 2sxc module to detect whether it is the original module on a page or a copy of the module being rendered in the theme.

A little more information: I have a case where I am making a manager page for a flyout menu, and it needs to display on the page what the flyout will look like as well as render this module in the theme. I have found that to render the module in the theme I need to use `this.GetScopedService<IRenderService>().Module()`, but the issue I am having is that I need to detect whether it is the original module on the page or the version being rendered in the theme through the IRenderService call as I need to add in some additional tags when it is the original to get it to display properly. Is there any way to check for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are rendering the module from the theme you can pass in Data. So when the module renders on the page, this data would be null. So simple add (or not add) to your output based on that. Might be as simple as (note: this is pseudo-code, I have not tried this)

```
...Module(pageId: 42, moduleId: 123, data: {})
```

and then

```
if (MyModel.Data is null)
{
  // add stuffs
}
else
{
  // don't add stuffs
}
```

This would also allow you to pass in settings or other stuff and do a variety of things differently from the theme vs. the "real" module output.

Comment: This did the trick! I fed the named parameter "data" a new anonymous object with a bool field:  `data: new {ThemeRender = true}` , and then in the view using RazorTyped I check for the existence of the key in the MyModel ITypedModel object: `if(MyModel.Get("ThemeRender", required: false) == null)`. If null that means it is the module on the page since MyModel only gets passed the data object if rendered in the theme. Note that you need to include required: false in the MyModel.Get() call as that tells it to return null if the key doesn't exist, otherwise it throws an error.

Comment: Honestly, it would be much cooler if you could detect this from within the View code, a MyView property or something? I remember doing something like this a few years back where I used Reflection to crawl up the call stack... that worked, but was messy and not code I would show to to anyone now without being embarrassed! ;)